# Conditional with if and ifelse not working

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

Every entry has one image {event_feature_image_01}, however, some entries have a second, third and forth image. I want to count backwards from the forth image {event_feature_image_04}. Every entry has one image. So that is the {if:else}.

I tried to put in 3 images using {if:else if} but Something is not right in the syntax  and I am not sure what it is.

```
{if event_feature_image_04} <img class="img-responsive osd-border" alt="Photo:{event_name}" src="{event_feature_image_04}" {if:elseif src="{event_feature_image_03}"} {if:else} src="{event_feature_image_01}" {/if}>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - show nothing at all if there is no image:

```
{if  event_feature_image_04 
  OR event_feature_image_03 
  OR event_feature_image_02 
  OR event_feature_image_01}
<img class="img-responsive osd-border" alt="Photo:{event_name}" src="
{if event_feature_image_04}{event_feature_image_04}
{if:elseif event_feature_image_03}{event_feature_image_03}
{if:elseif event_feature_image_02}{event_feature_image_02}
{if:else}{event_feature_image_01}{/if}
">
{/if}
```

Option 2 - show a default image if no `event_feature_image` is set:

```
<img class="img-responsive osd-border" alt="Photo:{event_name}" src="
{if event_feature_image_04}{event_feature_image_04}
{if:elseif event_feature_image_03}{event_feature_image_03}
{if:elseif event_feature_image_02}{event_feature_image_02}
{if:elseif event_feature_image_01}{event_feature_image_01}
{if:else}dummy_image.jpg{/if}
">
```

Comment: Awesome ... but I forgot that 2 out of the 30 entries don't have images. and now the class show an empty broader with not image inside.    [link]http://osd.seeingishosting.com/index.php/events/show/category/thursday_fiesta

Comment: Ahah.  OK.  One solution would be to have some overall condition around the <img> tag - so you get nothing appearing if there are no images, but that might mess up your HTML, so an alternative would be to put in a placeholder image if there is no other image set.  I've modified the code in answer to account for the two cases...